# Filter on calculated representation of some fields

Tags: python, django, filter

I have three numeric columns in my model that together create a string, which is presented to the user:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    aisle = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rack = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    plank = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
         return "{a:02}{r:02}{p:02}".format(a=self.aisle, r=self.rack, p=self.plank)
```

Now I want to filter on (part of) that string, so say I have three locations, `010101`, `010102`, `010201`, and I filter on `0101`, I want to select only the first two.

How would I do that, I looked into the `Q` objects and [available database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/), but I don't find a solution.

Comment: @mu無 that would introduce redundancy. In a non-django setup I would use a simple `WHERE human_readable(locationid) LIKE '%0101%'`. And create a `human_readable` function that does the trick for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, I managed to do it using a `Func`:

```
class LocationLabel(Func):
    function = 'CONCAT'
    template = '%(function)s(RIGHT(CONCAT(\'00\',%(expressions)s),2))'
    arg_joiner = '),2), RIGHT(CONCAT(\'00\','

models.Location.object.
   annotate(locationlabel=
        LocationLabel('aisle','rack','plank', output_field=CharField())
   ).
   filter(locationlabel__icontains=query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform a filter on a property, it has to be on fields.
In this case i think this will do what you require because **unicode** is just a formatted form actual integer value in fields:

```
Location.objects.filter(aisle=1, rack=1)
```

Comment: The thing is, `0101` will be my input, so I cannot easily split that (as it might mean `aisle=1,rack=1` but also `rack=1,plank=1`. Not mention input like `010`, or `123`

Comment: Input has to be standardised, if its `rack=1,plank=1` and `aisle=0` then it should be `000101` not `0101`. And `000101` is what you unicode will be returning as well. Is there a reason why input length is not fixed?

Comment: The input is not the data that gets into the database, it is my query string. I am filtering.

Comment: I understand that, but i am asking if you intend to query `rack=1 , plant=1`, the format should be `000101`. First two digits represent __aisle__ ,3rd and 4th __rack__ and last two digits __plant__. I mean it should always be fixed length like your unicode method is returning.

Comment: No. The query is a free-form string that searches in several columns. The location is one of them. The use should just be able to type in `010` and it could give me `010101`, `010201` and `020105`.

Comment: If you are using postgres then try this. Just update the __appname__ with your app name in which you have Location model. And pass the query to raw string in format.

`Location.objects.raw("select * from appname_location where concat(trim(to_char(aisle,'00')),trim(to_char(rack,'00')),trim(to_char(plant,'00'))) like '%{}%';".format(010))`

This will give you a generator, just iterate over it.